# What is this operator topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space with (norm $1$) Schauder-Basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Denote for $x\in X$ with $|\cdot|_x$ the seminorm on $\mathcal L(X)$ given by $|A|_x = \|A x\|$. Consider:

$$\|\cdot\|_1:=\sum_n 2^{-n} |\cdot|_{e_n} \tag{1}$$

This defines a norm and the topology of this norm is

1. Weaker than the uniform topology: You have $\|A\|≥|A|_{e_n}$ and then $\|A\|=\sum_n 2^{-n} \|A\|≥\sum_n 2^{-n} |A|_{e_n}$.
2. Strictly weaker than uniform topology in the case of $X$ a Hilbert space and $e_n$ ONB: Denote $\pi_n$ the orthogonal projection onto span of $e_n$, then $\sum_{n=N}^\infty \pi_n$ converges to zero in this topology but not in uniform norm.
3. Stronger than the strong operator topology.
4. Becomes equal to the strong operator topology upon restriction to bounded subsets.

For 3 and 4 see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664222/the-strong-topology-on-u-mathcal-h-is-metrisable). I don't know the relation to the $\sigma$-strong topology (generated by seminorms $\sqrt{\sum_n |\cdot|^2_{x_n}}$ whenever $\sum_n |x_n|^2$ converges), but it looks like this is weaker than the $\sigma$-strong topology.

Does this topology have a name? Is it remarkable that it has a norm?

A side question, if $\{x_n\}_n$ is a dense countable subset of $X$, then $\|\cdot\|_2:=\sum_n 2^{-n} \frac{|\cdot|_{x_n}}{\|x_n\|}$ gives another norm. I think it is equivalent to the above, but calculation looks unhappy. Is there a reason to expect it to be inequivalent to $\|\cdot\|_1$?

---

Remark: The norm is not submultiplicative, for example on a Hilbert space with $L$ the left shift, $R$ the right shift you have

\begin{gather}\|L^k\|_1 = \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty 2^{-n}=2^{-k} \qquad \|R^k\|_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}=1\\
\|L^kR^k\|_1=\|\mathbb 1\|_1 =1 \not≤\|L^k\|_1\cdot\|R^k\|_1=2^{-k}
\end{gather}

This makes it a bit less interesting.